# Close AlarmClock activity after calling startActivity(i);

Tags: android, alarm

I am building an app that uses the AlarmClock API to set an alarm by doing the following:

```
Intent i new Intent (AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

...

MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

this will start the Clock app in Android. What I want to do is after it opens up the app, I want to return back to MainActvity but I cannot call `finish()` or `onBackPressed()` because I do not have the alarm clock activity. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It´s a little bit confusing...if you haven´t the alarm clock app, how should it be possible to return from it? Can you please explain more detailed what the problem is?

Comment: After I call startActivity, the alarm clock app that's pre installed in Android will open. However, I want to return to my MainActivity after but I do not know how to.

Comment: Why do you want to return to your MainActivity after you open the Alarm Clock intent? You should state that as well.

Comment: I'd like to return to my MainActivity so I can do more things after setting the alarm. Or is there a way to set the alarm without calling startActivity/without opening the alarm clock app?

Comment: Returning to your app should be possible by quit the alarm clock app by backpress. It can´t be made by your app, I think you called `finish()` before you start the alarm clock app...this have to be deleted if you want to return to yours on back press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you want to close the Alarm clock app activity or you want to return back to your own app activity? Your title and description is different.

If it's the first, you can't since you don't own the app thus you don't have control over it's behaviors. For the latter, a back pressed is sufficient if you did not kill your own activity before moving to the alarm activity.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunally as they said you can't call your activity from the Alarm Clock app, but you can set the Alarm from your activity putting extras in the AlarmManager intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "ALARM NAME"); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClodk.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);//true if you want to set the Alarm without leaving your activity
startActivity(i);
```

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html